# Многие вопросы с php кодом вставлены через html snipet

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, сниппеты

По метке [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) многие вопросы вставлены через HTML сниппет.
Складывается ощущение, что что-то не так с формой ввода сообщения.
Посмотрев на форму ввода сообщение, я осмелюсь предположить что иконка вставки `JS` кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сильно похожа на иконку вставки обычного кода на других ресурсах/программах и люди на интуитивном уровне жмут кнопку `<>` вместо `{}`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может стоит задуматься о редизайне иконок?

Comment: Когда я задавал первый вопрос на SO - для меня было большой загадкой, как вставить код. Пришлось гуглить - в гугле ничего не находилось. Мрак. Оказывается я не один такой ущербный))

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр тултипы на кнопках не видно?

Comment: @Nofate  Расчитывал при нажатии получить bbcode-тег или попап, а получил то, чего не понял, помоему так) Ну и сниппет вставил, вместо того чтобы код выделить, за что мой код отредактировали и поставили минус :D

Comment: Есть такое дело, phpBB испортил людей. Markdown шокирует.

Comment: Меня вот, когда пишу на форумы с BBCode, ощущение не покидает, что в каменный век попал. Спасибо.

Comment: Поддержу вопрос. С интерфейсом явно что-то не так. К примеру, я только через год углядел нужную кнопку, а до этого я выравнивал код через многократные Ctrl+V или отдельный текстовый редактор с блочным выделением.

Answer (score 5):

Редизайн не поможет. Пиктограммы не стандартизованы, рисуются по вкусу левой пятки каждого дизайнера - а потому их изучение может сравниться с изучением китайского. Особенно в глазах неопытного пользователя, который не может уловить закономерности.

Исторически, пиктограммы появились для связи главного меню программы и панели инструментов. Предполагалось, что пользователь запомнит пиктограмму у пункта меню - и дальше будет быстро находить нужную кнопку на панели инструментов.

Но на SO меню нет - а потому и пиктограммы изучать негде. Кнопка помощи не спасает, потому что сама является пиктограммой. Кроме того, на нее страшно нажимать, когда уже написана часть вопроса или ответа: вдруг произойдет переход на другую страницу?

Всплывающие подсказки также не работают. Потому что пользователь не привык к ним. Потому что на многих сайтах про них забывают. В итоге рефлекс "наведи мышку на непонятное и подожди" атрофируется даже у тех, у кого есть. Кроме того, подсказку невозможно вызвать на устройстве с сенсорным интерфейсом.