# Существует ли общепринятое правило применения сниппетов?

Tags: обсуждение, сниппеты

Я раньше думал, что [code snippet] предназначен только для HTML/JS кода, который возможно исполнять в браузере. А PHP и любой другой следует помещать в тэг [code]. Поэтому я предлагал правки, когда новичок использовал тэг [code snippet] не по назначению, с вышеупомянутой точки зрения.

В связи с тем, что моя последняя подобная правка была отклонена автором ответа (но при этом другой участник ее принял), а сегодня я наткнулся на вопрос новичка, где [code] исправили на [code snippet], и правка была принята несколькими участниками, я стал сомневаться в верности своей точки зрения.

На мете эта тема еще не обсуждалась, самый близкий по тематике пост вот этот: [Многие вопросы с php кодом вставлены через html snipet](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3839/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-html-snipet). На англоязычной мете подобные вопросы обсуждались, и хотя какого-либо концептуального ответа никто не дает, общее отношение к применению сниппетов к любым вставкам кода отрицательное.
[Выборка по "when to use snippets"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=when%20to%20use%20snippets)

Следует ли при проверке вопросов и ответов обращать внимание на уместность применения сниппетов и исправлять на обычное выделение кода, если сниппет нельзя запустить в браузере?

Следует ли это делать только при внесении каких-либо иных правок в вопрос или ответ?

Следует ли писать комментарий пользователю, указывая на использование сниппета не по назначению?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Сниппет отличается от обычного куска кода тем, что под ним есть кнопка, позволяющая увидеть результат. А потому любой код, который не может быть исполнен прямо в браузере, не должен попадать в сниппет.

Добавление сниппета в чужой ответ - это, как я думаю, [незначительная правка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), и ее не следует делать участникам с репутацией меньшей 2000 если все остальное в ответе в порядке.

Удаление же некорректно поставленного сниппета (преобразование в блок кода) - это важное исправление. Не вижу причин, по которым оно должно быть отклонено.

Comment: Про незначительность не согласен - даже на enSO такие принимали.

Comment: @Qwertiy принимать-то принимали, но это не значит что такую правку стоило делать